# Why am I getting a The field type's enum value is invalid for this search message?

Tags: php, api, soap, netsuite

Here is the situation.

I'm trying to get the proper class name of the serialized inventory item, however, when I'm doing a search (see the code below):

```
   $type = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
   $type->operator = 'anyOf';
   $type->searchValue = array('serializedInventoryItem');
   $search->type = $type;   

   $invetoryRef = new RecordRef();    
   $invetoryRef->internalId = '522216';

   $params = new SearchMultiSelectField();
   $params->operator = 'anyOf';
   $params->searchValue = array($invetoryRef);
   $search->serializedInventoryItem = $params;
```

However, when I do a search, I'm getting the following message: The field type's enum value  is invalid for this search.

Why would I be getting the following error message?

Thanks!
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, instead of using the code above, I used the following code:

```
  $service = new NetSuiteService();
  $request = new GetRequest();
  $request->baseRef = new RecordRef();
  $request->baseRef->internalId = 522216; 
  $request->baseRef->type = 'serializedInventoryItem';
  $getResponse = $service->get($request);
```

That resolved the issue.